# Maximum Matching in Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching

I have 2D Array where each element is `O` or `Non Zero`, I have to collect all `1` elements. For Doing so I will hire a workers

```
`0` - dead coconut tree
`Non Zero` - living tree
```

A worker starts harvesting at a living tree  and continues harvesting along a straight line of trees in one of the four cardinal directions (i.e., north, south, east, or west). A worker stops harvesting coconuts when one of the following conditions is satisfied

- The worker comes across a dead coconut tree.
- The worker hits the edge of the plantation (i.e., there are no more
  harvestable trees in that direction).

For Example Array Look Like This:
[image]

So Minimum 4 workers are required 
[image]

**Question:**

I was shocked when i came to know this is `Maximum Matching Problem` , i had no idea how is it so. 
Following is Code which Mark the Horizontal and Vertical Strips with a index

```
m=1;
for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < c && a[i][j] < m) j++;

        while (j < c) {
            while (j < c && a[i][j] >= m) {
                h[i][j] = hcnt;
                j++;
            }
            hcnt++;
            while (j < c && a[i][j] < m) j++;
        }
    }
    int vcnt = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<c; j++) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < r && a[i][j] < m) i++;
        while (i < r) {
            while (i < r && a[i][j] >= m) {
                v[i][j] = vcnt;
                i++;
            }
            vcnt++;
            while (i < r && a[i][j] < m) i++;
        }
    }
```

So my Question is How to add edges and why  it's maximum matching problem and can someone explain the intuition   behind this why maximum matching works on this problem. 
[Original Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/ncr-codesprint/challenges/coconut-plantation)

Following Code Add the edges. I hade no idea how we are adding the edges and why is it working

```
int s = 0, t = hcnt + vcnt + 1;
    for (int i=0; i<hcnt; i++) addEdge(s, i+1, 1);
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<c; j++) if(a[i][j] >= m) {
            addEdge(1 + h[i][j], 1 + hcnt + v[i][j], 1);
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<vcnt; i++) addEdge(1 + hcnt + i, t, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is as follows: we need to take some vertical and horizontal lines in such a way that all trees are covered and the number of picked lines is minimized.

Each cell with a tree becomes an edge in the graph. Each vertical line becomes a vertex in the left part of the graph and each horizontal line becomes a vertex in the right part.  Now the problem is equivalent to finding a vertex cover in this graph. The size of the maximum matching is equal to the size of the vertex cover in any bipartite graph (it's a more or less well-known theorem).